# How to apply echo effect recorded file? - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, signal-processing, core-audio, audio-recording

I want record and play same time.
When play sound, how to apply echo effect?
How to use AudioQueue?
Can anyone help me out how can I achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example on how to record and play at the same time here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html

This example also shows you how to apply an echo effect:
https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way, I want this work on iPhone. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, I didn't do much with Core Audio myself. I just knew of these samples, because I was recently looking for something similar. I am not sure if and what of the code can be used in iOS. You have to try out yourself.